# Coprime sequences from a linear recurrence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Given the linear recurrence $a_n=5a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}$ and the initial conditions $x_0=0,x_1=1$ and $y_0=1, y_1=3$ we get the two sequences
$$(x_n)=0,1,5,23,105,\ldots\\
  (y_n)=1,3,13,59,269,\ldots$$
which seem to be coprime is the sense that $gcd(x_n,y_n)=1$ for every $n$ (I checked it numerically up to $n=100$).

To prove the conjecture I tried (without success) the induction principle and Bezout's lemma to generate numbers $r$ and $s$ with $rx_{n+1}+sy_{n+1}=1$ from the existence of numbers $p$ and $q$ with $px_n+qy_n=1$.
Second, I solved the recurrence with the result
$$x_n=\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta},\quad y_n=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\alpha^n+\beta^n)$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the characteristic equation $x^2=5x-2$. Again, I don't see how to derive a proof. I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: No idea whether this works, but maybe we can create an infinite continued fraction having the convergences $x_n/y_n$.

Comment: No counterexample upto $n=10^5$.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you, so we need definitely a proof.

Comment: Hint: $ $ if $\,p\,$ divides both $\,x_{n+2} = 5x_{n+1}-2x_n\,$ and $\,y_{n+2} = 5y_{n+1}-2y_n\,$ then $\,p\,$ also divides $x_{n+1}y_n - x_n y_{n+1},\,$ which is a power of $\,2\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can consider the field $\mathbb{F}_p[\alpha]$. Assume that some prime divides both $x_n$ and $y_n$. Since all terms in $x_n$ are odd, $p>2$. Now, we can see that $p \mid (\alpha^n-\beta^n)$ and $p \mid (\alpha^n + \beta^n)$. But this is impossible as it would imply that $p \mid \alpha$, which is not true.

You might need to give special attention to the case $p=17$ since the discriminant of the characteristic equation is $17$.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Bill, write the recurrence in the form $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n+2}+2x_n}{5}$ ( and similarly $y_{n+1}$) to obtain
$$x_{n+1}y_n-y_{n+1}x_n=\frac{x_{n+2}y_n-x_ny_{n+2}}{5}.$$
So any prime $p\neq 5$ that divides both $x_{n+2}$ and $y_{n+2}$ divides $x_{n+1}y_n-y_{n+1}x_n$.

On the other hand, the solution of the recurrence yields
$$x_{n+1}y_n-y_{n+1}x_n=\alpha^n\cdot\beta^n=2^n.$$
So $p$ must be $2$, a contradiction, as $y_n$ is always odd. But also $p=5$ is impossible as you can see e.g. with induction. Thank you @Bill!